# Where is the "Send mail to all users" action?

Tags: 8, rules

I installed and configured the Rules module.

When I try to add a rule like notifying a new comment to all users, I do not see the *Send mail to all users* action.

Is that normal? Is there any other module to install?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is normal that you do NOT see "*Send mail to all users*", because there is no such Rules Action in D8 (nor in D7). In D7 there is a Rules Action like "Send an eMail to all users of a selected role", but that one is not (or not yet?) available in D8.

However, within group "*System*", there is the Rules Action "Send eMail". If you  use that one, with "Send to", you can specify 1 eMail address per line. So if you enter the eMail address for each user on a single line, you have a kind of work around for what you're trying to do.

What you probably want to do later on (when the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module is more mature), is to use some type list of all your users, and use that list in combination with a "loop" (a typical Rules Action). If this was a D7 question, you could use the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module to create a view of all your users, and use that for such list.

With that, either you have to be patient a bit, or use the work around suggested above ...